# VBA Macro Checking range for multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, selection, vba

I wrote a macro to check a selection for a value, and if it fits that value, to replace it with something else. Ok this is pretty easy when it is just one value. When I try adding multiple values, I keep running into different errors. hopefully one of you can point out where I'm missing the point :)

```
 Sub PTranslate()
 Dim cell As Range
 On Error Resume Next
 For Each cell In Selection
 If cell = "DZC" Or "0654548" Then
 cell.Value = "Douglas C"
      ElseIf cell = "RLP" Or "0623344" Then
 cell.Value = "Ryan P"
 End If
 Next


 End Sub
```

Comment: Its worth mentioning that I started off with just one entry, but plan on making this 2-300 long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is this. The correct syntax is to refer to the object *each time* in multiple condition `If` statements.

```
 Dim cell As Range, sVal as String

 For Each cell In Selection

    sVal = Cstr(cell.Value2)

    If sVal = "DZC" Or sVal = "654548" Then 'sVal = "0654548" Then
        cell.Value = "Douglas C"
    ElseIf sVal = "RLP" Or sVal = "623344" Then 'sVal = "0623344" Then
        cell.Value = "Ryan P"
    End If

 Next
```

If you are going to have many lookup values it may serve you better to make a list in your workbook and replace the cell values with the associated value in the lookup list. You can also use `Select Case`, but that can even be ugly with ~ 300 options.

Assuming your build your list in `mySheet` in Range A1:B300, the code for that would be:

```
Dim cell As Range

 For Each cell In Selection

    If Not IsErr(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Value2, Sheets("mySheets").Range("A1:B300"), 2, 0)) Then

        cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Value2, Sheets("mySheets").Range("A1:B300"), 2, 0)

    End If

 Next
```

Comment: Ran into the same issue i was getting on my own- It would only filter the first selection. This time it didnt even bother with the OR part of the first IF criteria

Comment: see my edited code. I had a thought that may help. I see your sample data as well. Are you sure the leading zero will always be there (because it's not in your sample data). If it's not, get rid of the leading zero in the vba If statement.

Comment: Posted a screen shot of the result. Ill mess with it some more when I get home :)

Comment: It appears to be a leading '0' problem.

Comment: what is a leading "0" problem?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman You know I didnt realize that excel was taking the leading zero off. Is there a way to stop that? Or just account for it in the vba lines? Also this worked like a charm. 

Dumb question time:

Why declare the data type conversion as an object? Is it b/c it needs to be referenced on a per cell basis which is why my original code was failing?

Though I did learn alot form this: Value2 is my new go to, and cstr from my googling is pretty awesome too.

Comment: @DougCoats - setting `sValue` isn't necessary. I added that before I saw your data set as I add a hunch it was something in the way the data was translating with the written code. You can leave it. It won't hurt, in a way it's cleaner, and easier to read. I don't know how your data gets populated, but if you format the cells as text before you data comes in it will keep any leading 0s.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a a bunch Scott. Not only have you been pretty bad ass, I learned quite a bit. One day Maybe i'll graduate above "script kiddie" level XD

Answer (score 2):

Use 'Select Case' for a long list:

```
For Each cell In Selection
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case "DZC", "0654548"
             cell.Value = "Douglas C"
        Case "RLP", "0623344"
             cell.Value = "Ryan P"
        ...
        Case Else
             ...
     End Select
Next cell
```

Comment: tried this and it didnt work. However Ill go back to it in a bit. User error is a thing :)